# Rails: What's generating the view in this example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry if this is basic, but I've been thrown in the deep end at a job where nobody has ever written anything in RoR, including me, and asked to "fix" something.

I'm looking at a page in my web browser which is `domain.com/collect` -- and I've found that in the routes.rb file:

```
get '/collect' => 'payments#index', :as => :collect
```

And so I've assumed this means the `index` method in the `PaymentsController` class. I've found that method and its:

```
def index
end
```

And that's it. There's a parent class -- `PaymentsController < AppController` but the super method is never called, and if it was ... well, its not there, either.

So, what's generating the view here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The view is at `app/views/payments/index.html.erb`, and it's layout is likely at `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

Comment: so nothing needs to call it explicitly? it just renders that by default if you don't specify?

Comment: Correct, by default Rails looks for `app/views/CONTROLLER_PREFIX/ACTION_NAME.html.erb` where `CONTROLLER_PREFIX` is `Payments` in `PaymentsController`'s class name.

Comment: A little bit more: the index method is empty in your case because it didn't need to do any extra work, like setting instance variables or authorizing users, etc (some of this _could_ be in filters though, e.g before_filter). It doesn't need to call `super` because as Deefour said, it's just going to automatically try to render that view.